# VSCode Extension Run Code can't run C++ in terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new in C++. I like VSCode very much. I want to run my C++ code in VSCode and so I am using MinGW and Run Code Extension of VSCode.

MinGW setup worked and I could also run my C++ code in the output terminal in VSCode, but when I enabled Code Runner in the settings to run my code in the terminal (so that I can take inputs), I am getting this error:

```
 bash: cd: d:\CodeForces" && g++ inSearchOfAnEasyProblem.cpp -o inSearchOfAnEasyProblem && d:CodeForces"inSearchOfAnEasyProblem: No such file or directory
```

My Folder structure is: d://CodeForces//inSearchOfAnEasyProblem.cpp

I am trying to run this file: inSearchOfAnEasyProblem.cpp

I am using the Bash terminal. I tried to change the terminal to cmd, but when I click the run button of code runner, it always runs in a bash terminal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac1Db.png)

Can anyone please help me? I would have been grateful.

Comment: `d:CodeForces"inSearchOfAnEasyProblem` doesn't look like a valid path. Copy-paste error when writing the question, or is it the actual output?

Comment: It's the output when I try to run